# torch.save(model, PATH) error : NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '~/KoGPT2_checkpoint.tar'

Tags: pytorch, checkpoint

I'm using pytorch, and I want to use pytorch checkpoint

this is my code

```
import os

save_path = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/KoGPT2_checkpoint/'
torch.save(model, os.path.join(save_path+'KoGPT2_checkpoint.tar'))
```

and the error says

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in __init__(self, name, mode)
    213 class _open_file(_opener):
    214     def __init__(self, name, mode):
--> 215         super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
    216 
    217     def __exit__(self, *args):

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/KoGPT2_checkpoint/KoGPT2_checkpoint.tar'
```

I also tested this kind of code to solve this

```
import os

save_path = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/KoGPT2_checkpoint'
torch.save(model, 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/KoGPT2_checkpoint')
```

but the problem is, I couldn't make .tar file in my colab.
I could only make "KoGPT2_checkpoint" file, which didn't have any extension

I don't know why I'm getting this error
Could you guys tell me how to make checkpoints using pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

Provided path does not exist.

Possibly you have not mounted drive with the google colab. Try mounting and verify the path.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

Then give appropriate path

```
save_path = '/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/KoGPT2_checkpoint'
```